# 12.04/Gnome Classic/printer prints 1 job then rubbish

Tags: 12.04, gnome, printing

After finally updating to 12.04 with Gnome 3.4.2, I find my printer (HP LaserJet Professional P1606dn) is unable to print more than a single job properly. I must turn the printer off and on to print the next job. If not, it prints reams of rubbish. Any suggestions?

I had no problems installing the printer; it practically installed itself.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the latest HPLIP software.

Comment: Since you are on 12.04; you may want to consider upgrading to 14.04, as this is officially supported by ubuntu. This may solve your printer woes, just in the fact that the software stack is more recent. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04

Comment: I have the most recent version of hplip.

Comment: I am not keen to upgrade to a non-LTS version, but I am willing to try.